# Error:(25) No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

While I am trying to import my Cordova project to the android studio, the following issues I have faced , kindly give a solution to rectify this.

platforms\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(25) No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'
Error:(25) No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 41.92 secs
Information:3 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" 
android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.interlace.crewmis" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" 
android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity

android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
        android:label="@string/activity_name"
         android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver 
 android:name="cordova.plugins.Diagnostic$LocationProviderChangedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver 
  android:name="cordova.plugins.Diagnostic$NFCStateChangedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED" 
   />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:exported="false" 
android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.TriggerReceiver" 
/>
    <receiver android:exported="false" 
android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ClearReceiver" />
    <activity android:exported="false" android:launchMode="singleInstance" 
android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.ClickActivity" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
     <receiver android:exported="false" 
android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.TriggerReceiver" />
    <receiver android:exported="false" 
 android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.ClearReceiver" />
    <receiver android:exported="false" 
android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.localnotification.RestoreReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:exported="false" android:launchMode="singleInstance" 
 android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.notification.ClickActivity" 
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
    <activity android:label="@string/multi_app_name" 
  android:name="com.synconset.MultiImageChooserActivity" 
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" />
 </application>
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" 
 />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: post your AndroidManifest.xml also

Comment: see updated my question@TouhidulIslam

Comment: it may be caused by the android build tools version and gradle version, you can try to modify them

Comment: Have you added cordova-android-support-gradle-release plugin